# Big O-Notation - $g \in O(f)$ given. Prove that $O(g) \subseteq O(f)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Here is a rough idea of mine:
If $g \in O(f)$, then $g(n) \leq c * f(n)$ for large n and $c>0$.

If $l \in O(g)$, then $l(n) \leq r * g(n) \leq c * f(n)$ for large n and $0 < r < c$, therefore also $l \in O(f)$.
So we can conclude $O(g) \subseteq O(f)$

Comment: You are missing some quantification for $n$. Do the statements hold for all $n$? For at least one $n$? For all but finitely many $n$? …

Comment: Furthermore, you seem to be using the same symbol "$c$" for different variables. The constants you get from $l\in O(g)$ and from $g\in O(f)$ are not equal in general.

Comment: I made some improvements ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, taking non negative case, we have $$O(g)=\left\lbrace f: \exists C_f>0, \ \exists N,\ n>N,  f \leqslant C_f g\right\rbrace$$

Suppose holds $f \in O(g)$. This means by definition. $\exists C_f>0, \exists N_f,\ n>N_f,  f \leqslant C_f g$.

Now let's consider some $\phi \in O(f)$. By definition $\exists C_\phi>0, \exists N_\phi,\ n>N_\phi,  \phi \leqslant C_\phi f$. Now taking $n>\max(N_f,N_\phi)$ we will have $\phi \leqslant C_\phi f \leqslant C_\phi C_f g$, which gives $\phi \in O(g)$ i.e. required subset definition.

Comment: Did you also prove that $O(g) \subseteq O(f)$?

Comment: No. Generally from $f \in O(g)$ i.e. from $O(f) \subset O(g)$ we cannot conclude reverse.